# Pig equivalent for SQL's select* from tablename

Tags: apache-pig

Pig equivalent for SQL's select* from tablename

Comment: in Pig i want to look at the column names and data in it. But i am unable to get the o/p . The o/p which you get for Select * from table in SQL. Please help

Comment: yup but this is irrelevant to my question. I have looked for all possible sites for this but i not getting exact query and hence the question

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what is meant by "o/p".

But the equivalent for SQL's SELECT * FROM table

in Apache Pig is FOREACH alias GENERATE *;

[ http://hadooptutorial.info/pig-functions-cheat-sheet/ ]